# Apache .htaccess redirecting directory to querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i would like to redirect requests on my site from

host.com/*directory*

to

host.com/?institution=*directory*

so that users can access the main level categories of my site using a directory notation
I just have a hard time wrapping my head around the regex, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(directory)$ /?institution=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You may want to fix (or unfix, as the case may be) the part of the pattern within the parens.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)$ /?institution=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/$ /?institution=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: you wrote it in the opposite direction of what the OP wants.